# How can I hide/remove choice options when a certain condition has been met on a SharePoint 2007 List?

Tags: sharepoint, list, sharepoint-2007, choicefield

I am trying to create a list in SharePoint 2007 that has a choice field where after a certain number of them has been used, it will either hide or remove itself.

For instance, after three list items have been created with the option "Burgers" selected, users will no longer be able to see that option from now on.

Is there are way to do this without any code? If not, then what is a way with minimal coding required?

Comment: You can do it with SharePoint designer: [Sharepoint Conditional fields in Edit.aspx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360216/sharepoint-conditional-fields-in-edit-aspx)

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to limit the choices from the choice field without coding. you can try checking if InfoPath is able to do this but as far as I know you really need to code this function.